# Cache of others skins?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've been wondering.

Most games with custom content cache the custom content from others somewhere. Is there a way to find the custom skins of others somewhere in the Minecraft folder after you played online with others?

Basically, when I see a cool skin someone I'm playing with is wearing, I would sometimes like to "steal" it.

Comment: Considering the extremely small size of skins, they might just be cached in memory. I'm not aware of any minecraft caching mechanism that uses physical storage. The burden of storing data is usually on the burden of the server.

Comment: You could always use the Minecraft Skin Viewer (not official) and look up their username and then copy their skin in your favourite skin editor (assuming that you can't find it with a quick google search because they made it themselves).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, skins are cached in memory, however you can view other skins at: http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/[USERNAME].png

E.g. My skin would be at http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/mike4560.png

Answer (score 3):

Skins are typically stored in your `.minecraft` folder. There is a `skins` folder, which contains all cached skins in multiple folders. These are `.png` files, however they are not named as such; you have to rename them. You also don't get to see the usernames, just a generated number.

On windows the folder is typically in `%AppData%\.minecraft\assets\skins` (type / copy this in the folder browser address bar).

Note: Please don't copy other's skins without permission; it is disrespectful.

Answer (score 3):

Go to nameMC.com then search your username and BOOM! There it is, ripe for the download.

Comment: Not exactly true since the owner of the account can delist their previous skins if they're linked to namemc. Still upvoted because this is better then the last answer which doesn't work at all anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft does not cache any skins as files on disk, but for your interests for this topic I have some for you :-)

If you want to get a skin from a specific user from whom you know the username (with correct case!) then navigate to http://www.minecraft.net/skin/Username.png

For example: http://www.minecraft.net/skin/Notch.png to get Notch's skin.

I use this on our servers website to display pictures of online users and player cards showing the users appearance in game.

Comment: This is outdated now. You might want to update your answer.